# How to convert html component to pdf print in nuxt js projects - doc.fromHTML true usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, nuxt.js, jspdf

in my nuxt project ı want to convert my html compoenent to pdf. when clicked button ı want to convert compoenent with all color to pdf.

```
import {jsPDF} from 'jspdf'
 
export default {
 
    data() {
        return {
             margins : {  top: 80,   bottom: 60, left: 40,  width: 522  }  }
    },
    methods: {
        generatePdf() {
            const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4'); 
            doc.fromHTML(this.$refs.testHtml, this.margins.left, this.margins.top,{
                'width' : this.margins.width
            });
            doc.save('test.pdf');
        }
    }

}
```

in here , the problem is about  doc.fromHTML. in many project this way is valid but in nuxt  doc.fromHTML doesnt work . it gives error.

Comment: thx for editing my question but my priority is an answer for my question not editing

Answer (score 4):

I'm late but someone can use this solution.

Use this method:

```js
 printReport() {
     window.print();
  },
```

```html
<button onClick="printReport">Print !</button>
```

If you want to hide somthing when printing, use this in CSS.

```css
 @media print {
     .no-printme {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .printme {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use vue-html2pdf npm package this will solve your problem and also internally it uses jspdf, so you will get its configuration.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf

Comment: How are you approaching it?

Answer (score 0):

vue-html2pdf npm module does not work properly. Rather than you can try html2pdf module for convert html to pdf in vuejs.

Package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.1